# Avoiding race condition between validation for uniqueness and insertion

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions, django-1.7

I have a Django 1.7 beta 1 project with a standard user signup form.

Conceptually, it makes sense for the form validation to fail if the username is already taken.  However, the form validation and the saving of the successfully created user model are separate steps, so there's a race condition where the validation can pass but the actual `user.save()` can fail with an `IntegrityError`.

I'm unclear on what happens if both the form validation and the `user.save()` step are wrapped in the same `transaction.atomic()` block -- my assumption is that postgres will not create any locks when the table is read to check if the row exists, and therefore the transaction will not prevent the race condition at all.

Assuming that's the case, what is the best way to handle this?  Here are the options I'm considering so far:

- Skip the username uniqueness validation entirely and just catch the `IntegrityError` on save time, adding to the form errors list manually.  This is bulletproof, but moves some validation logic outside of the form definition.
- Do both the validation step and the try/except block around the `IntegrityError`.  This may add duplicate code, but now the form works in isolation and the use of the form in the view doesn't cause a race condition.

Comment: Not really elegant or anything, but you could maybe actually create the object in form.clean() and then make sure you populate that model instead of creating a new one on save. But that kind-of defeats the purpose of the entire form workflow, and is again not entirely immune to the race condition, so I'm very interested in better answers!

Comment: This looks like a form of insert-if-not-exists, and has the same problems: It can't be made race-free without the ability to take a predicate lock on a nonexistent row, which PostgreSQL cannot currently do. So you have to trap the integrity error and deal with it one way or the other.